# How to fix error caused by fnDeleteRow using DataTables API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I was using the [DataTables API](https://legacy.datatables.net/api) and I found a function that did exactly what I wanted it to, fnDeleteRow, which simply removes a table row by index. I ran it on it's own in my function:

```
function foo(index){
    console.log('Row '+index+' will be deleted...');
    fnDeleteRow(index,null,true);
}
```

However, since I run this function repeatedly every 10 seconds, I get a strange error.

```
Cannot set property '_aData' of undefined
```

Also, something weird about it. I've tried to track down the problem, and it always disappears when I had print statements (console.log()) into the file, right before the foo call. I think it may be taking a second to fully delete the row or something, because the very moment I remove this line, the errors start to show up again.

Comment: How are you passing `index` to function foo?

Comment: to fnDeleteRow? Yes.

Comment: Can you provide how you are passing your index param to foo function ?

Comment: table.fnDeleteRow() will return `undefined` if there is no at that specified index. and will return the deleted row if there is. This error may be due to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your foo function definition and add a condition to get the data based on the row index.

**You can delete the row, if you get the data otherwise you can do nothing. like below**
where `fnGetData` to get the data and `table` is dataTable instance.

```
function foo(index) {
  var rowData = table.fnGetData(index);
  if (rowData) {
    console.log('Row ' + index + ' will be deleted...');
    fnDeleteRow(index, null, true);
  } else{
    console.log('Unable to delete Row ' + index);
  }
}
```

## Demo

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sctybaLu/)